# Parsing a json object echoed by a php file is not working

Tags: php, json, parsing

so what i am trying to do is creating a php file that will get me some info from the database and return to me a json array so i can parse it in another php file like so :

```
$json = file_get_contents("generatejson.php");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

The json encoded and echoed is 100% valid. 
If i type the echoed json string that i'm getting directly in my file like this:

```
{"article_1":{"label":"myfirstvalue","oT":"myfirsttext"},"article_2":{"label":"myfirstvalue","oT":"myfirsttext"},"article_3":{"label":"myfirstvalue","oT":"myfirsttext"},"article_4":{"label":"myfirstvalue","oT":"myfirsttext"}}
```

The parsing works .

But if i try to echo it from php like this :

```
$data = array(
    'article_1' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_2' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_3' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_4' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),

);

echo json_encode($data);
```

the parsing is not working tho the json string returned from php is valid.
What should i do to make it work. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by _"parsing is not working"_? I just tried running your code and then decoding the encoded json string - everything worked fine.

Comment: This kind of question requires a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is because `file_get_contents()` returns the *contents of the file*, so what you are doing here is not running the `generatejson.php`, but instead reading the code into the variable. So you are actually setting the value of `$json` to the string:

```
$data = array(
    'article_1' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_2' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_3' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_4' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),

);

echo json_encode($data);
```

(Which is of course, not a valid JSON).

What I believe you are trying to do is run the code and assign the output to `$json`, in which case you will want `require()`:

`generatejson.php`:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'article_1' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_2' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_3' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    'article_4' => array(
        'label' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),

);

return json_encode($data);
```

`test.php`:

```
<?php

$json = require("generatejson.php");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($data);
```

When I run this, I get the output:

```
Array
(
    [article_1] => Array
        (
            [label] => myfirstvalue
            [oT] => myfirsttext
        )

    [article_2] => Array
        (
            [label] => myfirstvalue
            [oT] => myfirsttext
        )

    [article_3] => Array
        (
            [label] => myfirstvalue
            [oT] => myfirsttext
        )

    [article_4] => Array
        (
            [label] => myfirstvalue
            [oT] => myfirsttext
        )

)
```

Which I think is what you are after?

Comment: Of course, depending on the use case, if you are only doing this to keep the code in separate scripts, and all the processing will stay within PHP, you may as well do away with JSON altogether, since this is just encoding and immediately decoding, which is a waste. You could just `return` the array in the `generatejson.php` file, then when you `$data = file_get_contents("generatejson.php");`, `$data` will already be a PHP array.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Also note, in my follow-up comment, above, (I'm sure you got this, but just for accuracy, and can't seem to edit a comment) I meant `include`, not `file_get_contents`! Should pay more attention when copy-pasting, d'oh!